# Formatting margins in Word documents

Tags: microsoft-word, formatting, margins, ruler

I am formatting a document written by someone else and am frustrated by the wandering margins.  I have tried deleting all the margins and resetting but the problem remains.  The ruler at the top of the page also seems to reset at every page.  What am I missing ?

Comment: Why can't you select the entire document (Ctrl+A) and set the margins for everything?

Comment: Did the original author set different left and right margins for a booklet meant to be folded along alternate pages? BTW, one way around *very* messy indentation is to select all and paste into a new document *sans formatting*. Of course, alignment, font styles, hyperlinks, etc. would need to be applied, bit by bit, but sometimes it's the only way to salvage an idiosyncratic document.

Comment: In addition to Harry's suggestion, consider repairing the Word Document  .....   n Word, select File on the Ribbon, and then select Open. In the Open dialog box, click once to highlight your Word document. Select the arrow on the Open button, and then select Open and Repair

Answer (score 0):

### In Word, first distinguish between Margins and Indents.

**Margins** are a *Section* property and you seldom want to reset margins.
**Indents** are set for each  *paragraph* in a document. These can be left and right indents and are usually what people want to change when they are talking about margins.

Here is my [writing](https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/basic_formatting.htm#Margins_and_Indents) on this topic.

The ruler at the top of the page reflects the paragraph formatting for indents and tabs and the section setting for margins. It can be different in every paragraph.

So, having these concepts clear in your mind, unless top and bottom margins are involved, what we are talking about should be paragraph indents. These are ideally set in the styles being applied. That is probably not the case with your task, though.

Try selecting your entire text and with everything selected, organize the indents on the ruler the way you want. These can also be set using the Paragraph Formatting dialog box for more precision.

### If section breaks were in fact used to change margins, there are two approaches.

***Do either of these with a copy or at least with having a backup.***

**First approach** is to select the entire document and set the margins. This is done on the layout tab. This should handle the margin switches. *This was harrymc's suggestion.*

**The second approach** is more drastic and uses the **Replace** feature to remove all section breaks. **Ctrl+H** is the keyboard shortcut. Replace ^b with nothing or with ^p. That removes all section breaks and margin changes. Section breaks also carry headers and footers, orientation and columns, so you may have a mess there as well. If this is your situation, write back and we will get into macros to fix.